# How to use svg.js and plugins in angular 6 project

Tags: angular, svg.js

I created an Angular 6 project using the angular-cli.
I installed svg.js as well svg.drggable.js.
I addtionally created a new component called "draw".

I want to make a simple rectangle using svg.js. In order to do so in Javascript the HTML file needs a div-element with a property e.g. "drawing". However, when I put a div-element in the components html-file the rectangle is not created. Adding the div-element in the app-component solves this problem.

I'm not sure if it has something to do with hierarchie of the dom-element. But if so, it is even possible to use svg.js with a new component?

This what the draw.component.html looks like:
`<div id="drawing"></div>`

draw.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as SVG from 'svg.js';
import * as drag from 'svg.draggable.js';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-draw',
  templateUrl: './draw.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./draw.component.css']
})



export class DrawComponent implements OnInit {
  
  

   rect = SVG("drawing").size(500,500).rect(300,30).fill('FFBbAA').move(20,20)
  
   
  
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  
  
}
```

app.component.ts

```
<app-draw> </app-draw>
```

Comment: Add it to the scripts array inside angular-cli.json file to use everywhere

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.I still have to call <div id="drawing"></div> in **app.component.ts**. It won't work in **draw.component.ts**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ngx-svg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-svg) library, that would do exactly what you need. Check out the `svg-rect` documentation.